# DB2 keeps returning "duplicate name" when trying to add a non-existent column via Flyway with Spring Boot

Tags: sql, spring-boot, db2, flyway, db2-luw

How do I add columns to DB2 tables via Flyway? I have 2 flyway migration scripts. V1 is the initial creation of the database. V2 is trying to add a column to different tables that has been left out of V1.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1
ADD CODE VARCHAR(20);

ALTER TABLE TABLE2
ADD CODE VARCHAR(20);

ALTER TABLE TABLE3
ADD CODE VARCHAR(20);
```

This certainly seems simple enough. However, flyway gets a response of `DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-612, SQLSTATE=42711, SQLERRMC=CODE` which is the error for duplicate columns when trying to add more than 1 line of these at a time. So adding a column to TABLE1 works, same for TABLE2. But, if execute both I get the error.

How should I be structuring these queries so that they don't conflict?

Comment: Look deeper, specifically look at the emitted code, and in particular pay attention to the details. ,  if identifiers are quoted then case is significant, if no schema is specified then the implicit schema is significant, and if any of the objects have aliases (aka synonyms) then thing may not be what you think etc., and also check transaction control details. Check the initial create table lacks the column etc.

Comment: Flyway injects the schema via configuration files so we can have different environments. The identifiers are not quoted and all in CAPS. There are no synonyms. I'm not sure what you mean by emitted code? The resulting query flyway produces?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the DB2 error this is not a DB2 problem, but a Flyway one. You cannot add the same column to multiple tables with consecutive queries. There must be a query in between OR the queries must be in different migration files.

This works.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ADD CODE VARCHAR(20);
CREATE INDEX index1 ON TABLE1(CODE);

ALTER TABLE TABLE2 ADD CODE VARCHAR(20);
CREATE INDEX index2 ON TABLE2(CODE);

ALTER TABLE TABLE3 ADD CODE VARCHAR(20);
CREATE INDEX index2 ON TABLE3(CODE);
```